# Delete row in CSV python from an error from my Script

Tags: python, delete-row

I have at script to create user in a system. Sometime I get an error that the user is already in the system. So I want to finde the row with Username and delete the row from CSV file and save. How to do that?

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far (code) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with users or something like that you can best go for a SQL database.